# type(of :) function compiler warning in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I have upgraded the project from Swift 3 to Swift 4, but the compiler suggested that the conditions in the `if` can not call value of non-function type `'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')`. How to solve this?

```
func getHandler(_ type:AnyClass) -> CSHandler? {
    for handler in handlers {
        if type(of: handler) === type {
            return handler
        }

    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think compiler is getting confused with the parameter `type` and method `type(of:)` both have the same initial token. Can you change the parameter name from `type` to `pType` as below

```
func getHandler(_ pType: AnyClass) -> AnyObject? {
  for handler in handlers {
    if type(of: handler) === pType {
      return handler
    }
  }
  return nil
}
```

This should work for you and I would suggest you to file a bug report to apple regarding this issue

Comment: Thank you, really because of the type (of :) conflict between my type and the standard library, thank you for your answer